# My own substring function | valgrind showing some malloc errors I do not understand

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind

Task:

> Allocate (with malloc(3)) and return a substring from the string `s`. The substring begins at index `start` and is of maximum size `len`.
>
> Return value: The substring. `NULL` if the allocation fails.

Hello, after a few hours I decided to ask for some clarifications. I have the following functions and some error from Valgrind I can't understand, that shows up even if everything is correct. (`ft_strlen(s)` I call from my own library, where also lib for malloc is put).

```
char    *ft_substr(char const *s, unsigned int start, size_t len)
{
    unsigned int x;
    char        *a;
    unsigned int i;

    i = 0;
    if (s == NULL)
        return (0);
    if (start > ft_strlen(s))
    {   
        if (!(a = (char *)malloc(0*sizeof(char))))
            return (0);
        return (a);
    }
    if ((start + len) < ft_strlen(s))
        x = len;
    else
        x = ft_strlen(s) - start;
    if (!(a = (char *)malloc((x + 1) * sizeof(char))))
        return(0);
    while (i < x)
    {
        a[i] = s[start + i];
        i++;
    }
    a[i] = '\0';
    return (a);
}
```

I left there one error on purpose. If I am suppose to return null if allocation fails, why below instead of `0` should be `1`? Anyway it does not change the errors presented below.

```
if (!(a = (char *)malloc(0 * sizeof(char))))
```

ERRORS:

```
==4817== Invalid read of size 1
==4817==    at 0x483FED4: strcmp (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4817==    by 0x4039BC: main (ft_substr_test.cpp:28)
==4817==  Address 0x4dad0d0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 0 alloc'd
==4817==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4817==    by 0x403B58: ft_substr (in /home/tony/42cursus/0lvl_libft_1week/libftTester/a.out)
==4817==    by 0x4039A4: main (ft_substr_test.cpp:27)
==4817==
```

Comment: When you `malloc(0)`, the result can either be NULL, or a valid pointer that you can't use. From the error messages, it looks like you got the latter, and you passed the pointer to `strcmp`. After the malloc, try printing the pointer with `printf("%p\n", (void *)a);`

Comment: The code should be `if (s == NULL || start > ft_strlen(s)) return NULL;`

Comment: nah, i tried it and it didnt work @user3386109

Comment: aw, see [mcve].

Comment: This code is neither complete nor minimal - please post a full program (with `main()`) that is _just enough_ to demonstrate the problem, and no more.

Comment: This is a full code, it is just the function. I was trying to explain it best i can, sorry :(. The automatic test I got from a friend does testing and just wanted to know what that errors mean to know where to look for more informations :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function has multiple problems:

- the type of `start`, `x` and `i` should be `size_t`.
- `malloc(0)` has implementation defined behavior. You should allocate at least 1 byte for the null terminator and set it before returning the pointer to the empty string or return `NULL` if the specification says you should.
- the function should call `ft_strlen()` just once.
- the special case for `start > ft_strlen(s)` can be handled in the general case if an empty string should be returned.

Here is a modified version:

```
char *ft_substr(char const *s, size_t start, size_t len) {
    size_t i, slen;
    char *a;

    if (s == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    slen = ft_strlen(s);
    if (start > slen) {
        start = slen;
    }
    if (len > slen - start) {
        len = slen - start;
    }
    if (!(a = malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char)))) {
        return NULL;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        a[i] = s[start + i];
    }
    a[i] = '\0';
    return a;
}
```

PS: you may need to reformat the code to fit the local *42* norminette...

Comment: Thank you! I got what was wrong, that a of size 1 had to be '\0' terminated, hence error. About start. x and i. The function is defined this way in manual: ..(unsigned int start, size_t len) this is the reason I wrote that way ;). But thank you a lot for answer and i analyse itnow to see how to write my code more pretty also!

Answer (score 1):

On Linux systems, calling `malloc(0)` will not necessarily return a NULL pointer.  It could return a pointer that your can't write to but can pass to `free`.

So when you return the result of `malloc(0)` from the function the calling function sees a non-null pointer and attempts to dereference it.  Since this pointer essentially points to a buffer of size 0, attempting to read it reads past the end of the buffer, which is what valgrind is complaining about.

You can fix this by either returning NULL:

```
if (start > ft_strlen(s))
{   
    return NULL;
}
```

Or by allocating space for an empty string and setting the null byte:

```
if (start > ft_strlen(s))
{   
    if (!(a = malloc(1)))
        return NULL;
    *a = 0;
    return a;
}
```

A few other notes:

- `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1, so you can leave it out of size calculations
- Don't cast the return value of `malloc`.
- Use NULL instead of 0 for null pointers
- Parenthesis aren't required around the expression in a `return` statement.

Comment: Thank you!! I understood the problem i guess now.